# Is it possible to use gRPC with Fastify?

Tags: fastify, grpc-node

Looking around the docs, I don't see any support for gRPC with Fastify. Is there a way to use Fastify with gRPC as the transport protocol?

Comment: No, it supports `ws` but I never listen to grpc server implementation
I think this could be possible to write